# Resolve common external library in both App and third party SDK in iOS

Tags: ios

Both the app and a third party SDK use same external library. Since its the same set of symbols, I am unable to compile the app code because of duplicate symbol error.

Can anyone suggest an alternative or approach?

Comment: How do you use the third party SDK? Is it through CocoaPods? If YES, they should be able to declare the dependencies and avoid doubles imports.

Comment: no the third party SDK is used in the app as **.a** file and the external library is loaded through cocoapods.